# Regarding bit masking in C. Why (~(~0 << N)) is preferred than ((1 << N) -1)?

Tags: c, bitmask

I do know that **~0** will evaluate the maximum word sized bit 1s (and thus takes caring of portability), but I am still not getting why **((1 << N) - 1)** is discouraged?

Please share if you used the second form and got into any trouble.

Comment: Because not all C compilers/platforms use 2-complement for negative numbers.

Comment: @jv42 why does that apply? I see no negative numbers there, except ~0 but its negativity isn't needed for it to work

Comment: Can you provide a source where the `((1 << N) -1)` is discouraged?

Comment: @harold: The issue is if you do `unsigned int x = ~0;` in (for example) 1s' complement. `~0` is all-bits-set, and as a signed value that represents negative zero (or is a trap representation). So when it's converted to unsigned, the result is 0, not `UINT_MAX`. `unsigned int x = ~0;` does not take care of portability if by "portability" we mean "including non-2's-complement". The correct ways to do that are `unsigned int x = -1;` or `unsigned int x = UINT_MAX;`.

Comment: @SteveJessop Thanks for the comprehensive explanation :)

Comment: @SteveJessop ~0 *is* -1 with 2's complement, but -1 need not be "all bits set" (in case of non-2's-complement, ie never).

Comment: @harold: that's true, but I'm not talking about 2's complement. In a 1s' complement implementation which doesn't support negative zeros, `~0` is undefined behavior. So strictly conforming code cannot write `~0`. `~0u` is OK, though. And the same considerations apply to `(1 << N)` in sign-magnitude representation, as apply to `~0` in 1's complement, so they're equally bad as far as signed representation is concerned.

Comment: @SteveJessop that seems to argues in favour of `(1 << N) - 1` then, which could still fail but certainly less often (only when N >= 31)

Comment: @harold: well, if `N` isn't the width of `int` minus 1, then `(1 << N) - 1` certainly won't yield the representation with all bits set. I think that value is what's wanted. So I was assuming that `N` was just standing in for 31 on implementations with a 32-bit `int`, and some other value on other implementations. The fundamental problem is that on a 1s' complement representation, there might not *be* a signed value with all bits set, which means in strictly-conforming code you need to do your bit-twiddling in unsigned types.

Comment: Similar issues were addressed fairly recently in Michael Barr's blog: http://embeddedgurus.com/barr-code/2011/06/is-uint16_t-1-portable-c-code. There was a great reader comment which addressed this very issue.

Comment: @SteveJessop I was assuming N was not "#bits - 1", otherwise there wouldn't be a problem in the first place - just use UINT_MAX

Comment: @harold: yes, the fact that the questioner doesn't actually say what result he wants, doesn't make it any easier to advise how to do it! If `N` is smaller then there's no reason to discourage `(1 << N) - 1`.

Comment: -1 for presupposing the worse form is better rather than asking which is better and why, or if there's a better alternative to both.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look at these lines:

```
1. printf("%X", ~(~0 << 31) );
2. printf("%X", (1 << 31) - 1 );
```

Line `1` compiles and behaves like expected.

Line `2` gives the warning *integer overflow in expression*.

This is because `1 << 31` is treated by default as a **signed** int, so `1 << 31 = -2147483648`, which is the smallest possible integer.

As a result, resting `1` causes an overflow.

Comment: You can do `(1u << 31) - 1` without warning.

Comment: @Juraj Blaho: Yes, but that wasn't the question. `((1 << N) - 1)` simply doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you Dennis! yes it does warn.. :) But still can't overflow be ignored when used as bit mask?

Comment: @MS.: Signed overflow is UB, so it may or may not work depending on the compiler. Gcc does aggressive optimization based on the fact that signed integer should never overflow.

Comment: @R.. nicely put for saying that this answer is just plain wrong. It is really a pity that compilers don't warn about `1 << 31`. That it is `-2147483648` is just a coincidence. If `int` is 32 bit wide the result of `1 << 31` is not representable in `int` that's it, and we have UB.

Answer (score 4):

The first form is definitely not preferred, and I would go so far as to say it should **never** be used. On a ones complement system that does not support negative zero, `~0` may very well be a *trap representation* and thus invoke UB when used.

On the other hand, `1<<31` is also UB, assuming `int` is 32-bit, since it overflows.

If you really mean 31 as a constant, `0x7fffffff` is the simplest and most correct way to write your mask. If you want all but the sign bit of an `int`, `INT_MAX` is the simplest and most correct way to write your mask.

As long as you know the bitshift will not overflow, `(1<<n)-1` is the correct way to make a mask with the lowest `n` bits set. It may be preferable to use `(1ULL<<n)-1` followed by a cast or implicit conversion in order not to have to worry about signedness issues and overflow in the shift.

But whatever you do, don't use the `~` operator with signed integers. Ever.

Comment: I would never have expected that '1 << 31` is undefined behaviour. Literally all text I had read until today stated that a `signed int` can take all values from `-2147483648` to `2147483647`, both inclusive. Question: Does `#define INT_MIN (-2147483647 - 1)` fix this? I ask since this is what `limits.h` does in gcc, tcc and icl...

Comment: The fact that `signed int` can take all values in that range has nothing to do with the fact that `1<<31` overflows. It's simply a matter of arithmetic. 2^31 is greater than `INT_MAX` (assuming 32-bit int) and thus it's an overflow.

Comment: Then it seems like I'm not understanding well the bitshift operation. I learned once that `1 << 31`, rather than `2^31`, is `1` shifted 31 places to the left and padded on the right side with `0s`. That would yield `10000000 00000000 00000000 00000000` in binary or `0x80000000` in hexadecimal or `-2147483648` as signed integer. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: In C, `x<<y` is simply the arithmetic operation x*2^y`. The fact that it corresponds with bit shifting is treated as a coincidence.

Comment: I don't believe this can invoke undefined behavior. C99 6.3.1.3 §3 `"Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised."`

Comment: @Lundin: That language is about type conversions. No conversion is taking place here. If you used `1U<<31`, then converted that to `int`, the behavior would be implementation-defined, not undefined. And if you used `(1U<<31)-1`, the result would be within the range of `int` and thus the conversion would be well-defined.

Comment: @R ~ comes with integer promotion, but ok, in this specific example there won't be any type conversion as the 0 is of type signed int. So you are correct, I found the relevant part of the standard is 6.2.6.2 §4 which indeed states that this is UB. So formally ~0 is indeed bad practice, even though personally I have yet to see a one's compliment system in the real world.

Answer (score 1):

I would discourage both, shift or complement operations on signed values is simply a bad idea. Bit patterns should always be produced on unsigned types and (if even necessary) then transposed to the signed counter parts. Then using the primitive types is also no so good as an idea because usually on bit patterns you should control the the number of bits that you are handling.

So I'd always do something like

```
-UINT32_C(1)
~UINT32_C(0)
```

which are completely equivalent and at the end this comes just to use `UINT32_MAX` and Co.

Shift is only necessary in cases you don't shift fully, something like

```
(UINT32_C(1) << N) - UINT32_C(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not prefer one to another, but I've seen many bugs with `(1<<N)` where the value had to be 64-bit but "1" was 32-bit (ints were 32-bit) and the result was wrong for N>=31. 1ULL instead of 1 would fix it. That's one danger of such shifts.

Also, shifts of ints by CHAR_BIT*sizeof(int) or more positions (similarly for long long's (which are often 64-bit) by CHAR_BIT*sizeof(long long) or more positions) aren't defined. Because of that it may be safer to shift right like this: `~0u>>(CHAR_BIT*sizeof(int)-N)`, but in this case N can't be 0.

Comment: Doesn't `~0` also have the problem of being 32 bits?

Comment: @harold: ~0 will be 32-bit if ints are 32-bit. But what problem are you referring to? Oh, understandably, in `~0u>>(CHAR_BIT*sizeof(int)-N)` `1 <= N <= CHAR_BIT*sizeof(int)`. You can extend this expression to long-long appropriately.

Comment: Well I mean, it doesn't give a reason to pick ~(~0 << N) over (1 << N) - 1

Comment: @harold: I just pointed out a few problems I'd encountered with such constructs. Something to watch out for.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: corrected a stupid error; and noted possible overflow problems.

I have never heard that one form is preferred over the other. Both forms are evaluated at compile time. I always use the second form, and I've never gotten into any trouble. Both forms are perfectly clear to the reader.

Other answers noted the possibility of overflow in the second form.

I see little to choose between them.

Comment: How could the first be evaluated at compile time and the second could not?

Answer (score -2):

**Why Discouraged**
~0 is a *single cycle* operation and hence faster 
((1<first do a shift and *then a subtraction* which is an arithmetic operation. so due to subtraction it *will consume a lot of cycles* and hence unnecessary overhead.

**More**
more over, when you do ((1 << N)-1) or ((M << N)-1) is same, assuming N refers to M's size in bits because it will flush all the bits. here 1 is integer, typically 32 bit on almost all the present platforms 32/64 bit, so N can be assumed 32.

The result will however not same if you typecast 1 to long and do   (((long)1 << 32) -1).
here you need to use 64 in place of 32, 64 being the size of long in bits.

Comment: i am also interested to know if the conversion ((1<<32)-1) will be done at compile time or at the run time.

Comment: That's not true for any platform I know, but more importantly, any compiler that isn't completely braindead will use zero instructions and just calculate the constant.

Comment: harold: what s not true?  <br> in 1<<N, 1 will not be considered an int?

Comment: Neither shifts nor subtraction would consume lots of cycles. Shifts by more than 1 used to be slow back in the stone age though.

Comment: which means the logical shift and arithmetic operations have same complexity? i don't feel that :)

Comment: essentially yes, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrel_shifter  
though off the top of my head, Core2 has a lower thoughput for shifts than for "simple" ops (2/clock vs 3/clock) - doesn't matter though, it will be a constant anyway, with no shifting being done at runtime

Comment: If N is a constant, which I think we can assume, shift and complement operators are both going to be optimized to constants, so there is no difference in efficiency between the two examples.

Comment: @Lundin: Why must N be a constant?

Comment: @Juraj If it wasn't a constant, it would not be possible for the compiler optimize it at compile time. The compiler can still of course make predictions, if you have an auto variable on the stack like `int N=5;` and that variable isn't touched before the shifting, then the compiler can still treat it like a constant. But as soon as "N" is changed in runtime, the compiler can't do a thing.

Comment: @Lundin: I understand that. I just wanted to point out that there are situations when the whole term could not be optimized to a constant. And in these situations it makes sense to think about performance differences between the two options.

Comment: @Juraj No, I don't think that makes sense. ~0 and the shift implementation are only equivalent if the shift implementation is using a constant. I wouldn't expect the number of bits in an integer to vary in runtime...

Comment: everyone gives reason for +1, why are you not giving for -1?

Comment: @ Juraj
if N is not a constant equal to sizeof the 1 used above(32 for int, 64 for long), what purpose does it solve. For 1, best asumption of the type of the 1 is int. if we say ((1<<4)-1), i dont see anything reasonable doing it without a constant size N, with the value of N mentioned above.
if you have something good to quote with N as a variable having an arbitrary value, please specify the usability.